# :/: RPCPROG_NFS: RPC: Program not registered

Tags: freebsd, fedora, nfs

I tried to share the root / from a fedora 9 to a freeBSD while when I tried to mount the / folder it complained with "[tcp] nfs_server:/: RPCPROG_NFS: RPC: Program not registered". I followed the below steps to setup on the fedora nfs server:-

Add the below line inside the /etc/exports

```
/       nfs_client(rw,no_root_squash,sync)
```

restart the nfs related service

```
service portmapper restart
service nfslock restart
service nfs restart
```

export the filesystem using the below command:-

```
exportfs -arv
```

On the nfs client, I have troubleshoot using the below command:-

```
rpcinfo -p nfs_server
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind
    100024    1   udp  32816  status
    100024    1   tcp  34173  status
    100011    1   udp    817  rquotad
    100011    2   udp    817  rquotad
    100011    1   tcp    820  rquotad
    100011    2   tcp    820  rquotad
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100021    1   udp  32818  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  32818  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  32818  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp  32819  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  34174  mountd
    100005    2   udp  32819  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  34174  mountd
    100005    3   udp  32819  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  34174  mountd


showmount -e nfs_client
Exports list on nfs_server:
/                                  nfs_client
```

What else did I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I can mount the nfs using another linux machine, and I found that my freebsd rc.conf doesn't have the below line seems to be the root cause of the problem:-

```
nfs_client_enable="YES"
```

What does that line do? Can a FreeBSD server be a NFS client without booting up with nfs_client_enable="YES" inside the rc.conf?

Comment: Short answer - Please read the FreeBSD handbook (http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook) - It explains *everything*.  Longer answer - You MUST enable the NFS client functionality (which in turn enables the portmapper - the root cause of your problem) for a FreeBSD system to function as an NFS client.  If a service is not enabled a `start` or `restart` won't make it run.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem recently connecting to an old Redhat server.
After lots of shouting and swearing I fired up wireshark and worked out
that it was expecting a udp connection against tcp:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs tmif1:/rtdf /imports/tmif           
[tcp] tmif1:/rtdf: RPCPROG_NFS: RPC: Program not registered
^C
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o udp,ro  tmif1:/rtdf /imports/tmif
$ mount -t nfs

tmif1:/rtdf on /imports/tmif (nfs, read-only)
```